# A particular holomorphic map from the unit disc to a domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $M$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\lambda_z, \lambda_w\in \mathbb{D}$. Let $z,w\in M$. And $\phi: \mathbb{D}\longrightarrow {M}$ be a holomorphic map such that $ \phi(\lambda_z)=z$ and $\phi(\lambda_w)=w$.
Will the existance of $\phi$ imply the existance of another map $\psi : \mathbb{D}\longrightarrow {M}$ such that $\psi(0)=z$ and $\psi(\mu)=w$, for some $\mu\in (0,1)?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ is of the form

$$f_{\alpha,\vartheta}(z)=e^{i\vartheta}\frac{z-\overline{\alpha}}{1-z\bar{\alpha}}$$

Thus, given two points $\lambda_z,\lambda_w$, there exists one and only one automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ such that $f(\lambda_z)=0;f(\lambda_w)\in (0,1)$, which is obtained setting $\alpha=\lambda_z;\vartheta=-\arg(f_{\lambda_z,0}(\lambda_w))+2k\pi$. 
Given this function $f$, your desired $\psi$ is $\phi\circ f^{-1}$: in fact $\phi\circ f^{-1}(0)=\phi(\lambda_z)=z;\phi\circ f^{-1}(\mu)=\phi(\lambda_w)=w$